# VLC intermittently not findind video from RTMP stream

Tags: vlc-media-player, rtmp

I've got an nginx-rtmp box that I use for RTMP streaming.  Watching these streams via flash player on a webpage works perfectly, but in VLC I have serious issues either natively or with RTMPdump.

1. By opening a Network Stream in VLC - Regularly getting a message of "Picture is too late to be displayed" and stuttering video as a result, but otherwise fine
2. Via RTMPdump - Quite often I get no video stream but the audio is fine
3. Via Livestreamer - Quite often I get no video stream but the audio is fine

At this point I'm adamant that it's a VLC issue, but I've no idea how to resolve it, if it's at all resolvable.

Any thoughts?